# Soft delete records in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, soft-delete

I'm using the paranoia gem on my Rails backend to manage soft deletions of records, however calling `destroyRecord()` on the Ember model causes it to be marked as deleted, hiding it from the collection on the frontend. On a page refresh, the record re-appears since it actually still exists in the backed albeit with a `deleted_at` timestamp set.

What is the best way to handle this in Ember? I'd like to be able to call `deleteRecord()` and not have the `deleted` flag set, but only for this model.

Answer (score 0):

If your records are soft deleted, then they shouldn't be present in your API response when they have a `deleted_at` . If they are, then you have some changes to make on your backend so that they aren't passed to the frontend.

If for some reason you want all of the records to be passed to the frontend even if they have a `deleted_at` date, then you should implement a computed property, something like:

```
isSoftDeleted: computed.notEmpty('deleted_at')
```

and you could create another one that blends both types

```
isGone: computed.or('isSoftDelete', 'isDeleted')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have clarified that...I have a checkbox to show/hide deleted records, and I do include deleted records in the API response (via an `include` param)

I ended up solving this with `ember-custom-actions` and a custom action named `softDelete` that issues a `DELETE` request without marking the record as deleted in the store. It's working out well.

Comment: Awesome!  I wasn't actually familiare with `ember-custom-actions`. I'm going to install that in my app NOW :)